# Adding Highcharts chart to draw2d canvas

Tags: javascript, highcharts, draw2d-js

I was wondering if there is a mean to add a graph made with **Highcharts** into a **draw2d** canvas. I tried to use the class made to import external SVG [SVGFigure](http://www.draw2d.org/draw2d_touch/jsdoc_6/#!/api/draw2d.SVGFigure), but it seems like the SVG is too complex to be used with this class according to [this](http://www.draw2d.org/draw2d_touch/jsdoc/#!/guide/extending_svg_figure) and my [test](https://jsfiddle.net/caqmefd6/19/).

```
draw2d.SVGFigure;
```

Thank you for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out a solution, converting the svg to an image and use **SetFigure** class from **draw2d** to insert it in the canvas.

```
draw2d.SetFigure;
```

You can find an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/who0cvsg/49/) of the implementation with canvg or with vanilla js.